# Read in large CSV file in R and export as multiple RData files using number of rows and skip

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, export, rdata

I'm attempting to import and export, in pieces, a single 10GB CSV file with roughly 10 million observations. I want about 10 manageable RData files in the end (`data_1.RData`, `data_2.Rdata`, etc.), but I'm having trouble making the `skip` and `nrows` dynamic. My `nrows` will never change as I need almost 1 million per dataset, but I'm thinking I'll need some equation for `skip=` so that every loop it increases to catch the next 1 million rows. Also, having `header=T` might mess up anything over `ii=1`since only the first row will include variable names. The following is the bulk of the code I'm working with:

```
for (ii in 1:10){
      data <- read.csv("myfolder/file.csv", 
                         row.names=NULL, header=T, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=F,
                         skip=0, nrows=1000000)
      outName <- paste("data",ii,sep="_")
      save(data,file=file.path(outPath,paste(outName,".RData",sep="")))

    }
```

Comment: Create a vector of the number of rows to skip and index it with your `[ii]`?

Answer (score 1):

(Untested but...) You can try something like this:

```
nrows <- 1000000
ind <- c(0, seq(from = nrows, length.out = 10, by = nrows) + 1)
header <- names(read.csv("myfolder/file.csv", header = TRUE, nrows = 1))

for (i in seq_along(ind)) {
  data <- read.csv("myfolder/file.csv", 
                   row.names = NULL, header = FALSE, 
                   sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                   skip = ind[i], nrows = 1000000)
  names(data) <- header
  outName <- paste("data", ii, sep = "_")
  save(data, file = file.path(outPath, paste(outName, ".RData", sep = "")))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ananda! A colleague also simply recommended using an outside program like CSV Splitter to do the trick quickly and outside of R to save resources, so I probably should've thought of that first. Regardless your suggestions are very helpful!

Comment: @Foxer, also look at `fread` for reading in the data more quickly than using `read.csv`.